# Javascript - jquery,accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="accordionButton">Personal Information</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">      
    Personal text
    </div>
    <div class="accordionButton">Experience</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">
    Experience information
    </div>
    <div class="accordionButton">Training</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">
    No skills
    <div class="accordionButton">Career</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">
    Never had a job
    </div>
    <div class="accordionButton">Referers</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">
    None.
    </div>
</div>
```

This code works how i want it to. It is a horizontal accordion. However, when it is loaded on my webpage, they content divs have to be hidden for my jquery to work.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // When div is clicked, hidden content divs will slide out  
    $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');    
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    });


    // Close all divs on load page  
    $("div.accordionContent").hide();

});
```

If i don't hide the divs, all the divs display. Is there any way to display the 1st page without changing too much of my jquery or would i have to set different class names for the button and the content so that when a specified button is clicked, the affiliated content will slide out for that button div?

Comment: Do you realise there's already a jQuery UI control for this. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery selector for first div and set it as `show()`. Something like :

```
  $('div.accordionContent:first').show();
```

Comment: i managed to remove the bit of jquery about closing all divs on the load page by setting the div accordionContent to display none in css. However, with the function you gave me, it still doesn't do anything. not getting any errors or anything in the javascript console, im adding:  $('div.accordionContent').first().show();
 });
 
underneath the click function.

Comment: @AnthonyDo Maybe we got the question wrong. It's working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/t9vYY/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.accordion = function(settings) {
        accordion = $(this);
    }
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('div.accordionContent').click(function() {

            if($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            }

            $('div.accordionContent').filter(':visible').slideUp();
            $(this).next().slideDown();
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle) instead of IF statements....

Answer (score 0):

Try this very simple solution

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="accordion-content">
        <div class="accordion-title">Title</div>
        <div class="accordion-toggle">Toggle content</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="accordion-content">
        <div class="accordion-title">Title</div>
        <div class="accordion-toggle">Toggle content</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="accordion-content">
        <div class="accordion-title">Title</div>
        <div class="accordion-toggle">Toggle content</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.accordion-content .accordion-title').on('click', function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.accordion-title').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $(".accordion-toggle").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
});
```